# Outer merge pushes non-matched lines to bottom

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm merging two dataframes together with an outer join. It seems to work but anything that doesnt match on the 2nd dataframe gets pushed to the bottom of the merged dataframe. Here are examples of the two dataframes,

| A_1 | B_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 54 |
| 1100 | 1300 |
| 450 | 600 |
| 350 | 560 |

| A_2 | B_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1200 | 1400 |
| 1100 | 1300 |
| 500 | 600 |
| 350 | 560 |

I use this

```
final_df = pd.merge(one_final_df, two_final_df, left_on=['A_1', 'B_1'], right_on=['A_2', 'B_2'], how='outer')
```

The results look like this where what didnt match on the 2nd dataframe got pushed to the bottom of the merged dataframe,

| A_1 | B_1 | A_2 | B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 54 | nan | nan |
| 1100 | 1300 | 1100 | 1300 |
| 450 | 600 | nan | nan |
| 350 | 560 | 350 | 560 |
| nan | nan | 1200 | 1400 |
| nan | nan | 500 | 600 |

Is there away to make it look like this though where it skips over lines that dont match in the 1st dataframe?

| A_1 | B_1 | A_2 | B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 54 | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | 1200 | 1400 |
| 1100 | 1300 | 1100 | 1300 |
| 450 | 600 | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | 500 | 600 |
| 350 | 560 | 350 | 560 |

Comment: If your only problem is the order that do sort_values()

Answer (score 1):

You can try sort the merged dataframe by the indices of `df1`/`df2`:

```py
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

final_df = pd.merge(
    df1, df2, left_on=["A_1", "B_1"], right_on=["A_2", "B_2"], how="outer"
)

final_df["index_x"].update(final_df["index_y"])

print(final_df.sort_values(by="index_x", kind="stable")[["A_1", "B_1", "A_2", "B_2"]])
```

Prints:

```
      A_1     B_1     A_2     B_2
0    23.0    54.0     NaN     NaN
4     NaN     NaN  1200.0  1400.0
1  1100.0  1300.0  1100.0  1300.0
2   450.0   600.0     NaN     NaN
5     NaN     NaN   500.0   600.0
3   350.0   560.0   350.0   560.0
```

---

Initial dataframes:

```
    A_1   B_1
0    23    54
1  1100  1300
2   450   600
3   350   560

    A_2   B_2
0  1200  1400
1  1100  1300
2   500   600
3   350   560
```